# Pub get 'Connection closed before full header was received' Angular + Polymer

Tags: dart, dart-polymer, angular-dart, dart-pub

I am trying to get packages from the PUB with the following:

```
name: 'ch_padart'
version: 0.0.1
dependencies:
  angular: "1.1.0"
  angular_node_bind: any
  polymer: ">=0.15.5+2 <0.16.0"
  core_elements: ">=0.6.0+4 <0.7.0"
  paper_elements: ">=0.6.1 <0.7.0"
  web_components: ">=0.9.0 <0.11.0"
  browser: ">=0.10.0+2 <0.11.0"
dev_dependencies:
  unittest: ">=0.11.0+5 <0.12.0"
  mock: ">=0.11.0+2 <0.12.0"
transformers:
- angular:
      html_files:
      - web/index.html
- polymer:
      entry_points: web/index.html
      lint: false
```

but the end result is always 'Connection closed before full header was received'
If you remove angular OR polymer (and elements) and then run pub get, there is no issue and all download and runs fine. No other warnings are displayed and --verbose yields nothing helpful that I can see.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you run `pub get -v` from command line you will see that pub is working quite hard but can't find a compatible set of dependencies. There was a similar issue recently that the I guess the collection package was required in different dependencies with non-overlapping version constraints.
This is quite common when using Angular with Polymer.
You might need to investigate the dependencies manually to find the cause.

Maybe you get some feedback from `pub get` when you remove all dependency constraints and then start adding them again one by one.

Comment: But this spec file worked PERFECTLY two weeks ago. Why would it not work now? I have not changed the version numbers.

Comment: Did you run `pub get` or `pub upgrade`? Do you have the `pubspec.lock` file from the state where it worked?

Comment: pub get and no I don't as my git .ignore file contains the .lock file.

Comment: I usually check in the pubspec.lock file because of this even when it's not recommended for packages (only apps AFAIK). I guess a new version of some depencency misleads pub and it searches for a long time where it doesn't lead to a solution.

Comment: So what should I do? This is very annoying and is delaying development.

Comment: Sure it is, but it is not easy to solve. You have somehow to find the culprit and adjust the dependency constraints to lead/force pub in the right direction.

Comment: I solved it by specifying each dependency manually. e.g. polymer: "0.15.5+2" instead of polymer: ">=0.15.5+2 <0.16.0"

Answer (score 0):

the pubviz packages helps to resolve this kind of issue as well: https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/pubviz

Comment: I tried it and it didn't work. I guess pubviz needs the pubspec.lock file or something else which is not available until the dependencies are resolved or maybe I did something wrong.